# Looking for a Backup Solution: Pure IPv6 Hyper-V Cluster

Tags: backup, hyper-v, ipv6, cluster

We're searching for a backup solution that is able to backup Hyper-V clusters in a pure IPv6 environment.

Based on my current knowledge, Microsoft's DPM seems to be the only option right now. With veeam the most popular backup solution seems to be [completely unaware of the rise of IPv6](https://forums.veeam.com/vmware-vsphere-f24/ipv6-support-in-veeam-v9-t30560.html) and upcoming competitors like Altaro (tested), Carbonite (asked for) and Vembu (asked for) don't have any plans to support it either.
[[Update: Found another solution called "Nakivo", which doesn't support IPv6 either]](https://helpcenter.nakivo.com/display/KB/IPv6+Support)

Googling for IPv6 capable backup software in combination with Hyper-V won't lead to a single relevant search result.

Do you have any suggestions or products in mind? I am completely aware of the controversialness of pure IPv6 deployments, but that is not the point i want to discuss here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seriously? I am a happy DPM user here and I am not running pure IPV6 backbone (just as note); but what you line out here is a sign of ignorance that is impossible. How can those products NOT have at least PLANS to support it? Shame.

Comment: Yeah, seriously. There are lots of backup products that also promise Ipv6 and totally fail in their implementation. It's just not important to a lot of organizations, since most infrastructure runs on ipv4 even if they use Ipv6 publicly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backula supports Ipv6 since around 2010, and is more than capable of backing up hyperv hosts and guests in addition to entire working hyperv clusters.

Comment: Just a small follow-up for people here who may wonder if we're using Backula now: Unfortunately our scenario with the amount of vms and hosts would result in a absolutely unaffordable pricing. The solution and the presales communication looked promising, though. But we had to talk about the pricing before we could test it, as they don't provide a HyperV-based demo environment. 
Nevertheless i'd recommend everyone to have a look at their solution. The fact, that it was unaffordable for us does not mean, that it is generally expensive. Maybe our scenario was just kind of "unlucky".

Comment: Hm, that's a real thing. The features you want for hyper-v integration do indeed demand their enterprise product rather than the community edition if you want it to work "out of the box".  It's very possible to make the community edition work extremely well with hyper-v hosts, but it requires the installation of several external community modules to handle things like single file restore, client triggered backups, etc. Their support for the enterprise product is really good, but yeah it's extremely expensive for even mid-sized deployments.